# I could buy a new car

Tags: modal-verbs

In the following sentence, what does "could" mean?

> If I got $40,000, I could buy a new car. Actually, I'm broke.

Does it mean possibility or ability?

Comment: What do you see as the difference in meaning between possibility and ability? If you answer that, you can probably answer the question yourself.

Comment: If we had some ham we could have ham and eggs. If we had some eggs.

Comment: If I had this sum of money, I would have the ability to buy a new car, but I might or might not buy one.

Answer (score 1):

It has the "would be able to" sense of "could"

Of course, as a human with free will, if you are able to do something, it is possible that you will do it.  So without further context both "be able to" and "possibly will" senses overlap, and there isn't really any difference

It would not be wrong to say:

> If I had $40,000, I could buy a new car, but I wouldn't because I can't drive.

("able to" but "will not")

But it also would not be wrong to say

> If it gets any colder, it could start to snow.

(indicating possibility, not ability - you wouldn't say "It is able to snow".)